# trying to identify variable that differentiate dev, prod and local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, development-environment

I have below variable that will differentiate local and dev

```
 export const isDevelopmentMode = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

below are the urls for three modes

local : `http://localhost:3000/projects`

dev: `http://abc-dev.azurewebsites.net/projects`

prod: `https://abc.eng.com/projects`

Now i am trying to hide some routes only in prod environment using `isDevelopmentMode` variable it is working fine in prod. But the problem is with `dev` mode, it is hiding routes in `dev` mode as well, When i access this url(`http://abc-dev.azurewebsites.net/projects`) i could not able to see the routes.

Could any please let me know how can i show the routes on dev mode as well and below is the code related to routes hiding.
Many thanks in adavance

```
  isDevelopmentMode &&  { 
  type: 'subMenu',
  title: 'Construction',
  icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/library/construction-material-type',
      exact: true,
      title: 'Construction Material Type',
      icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,              
    },
    {
      path: '/library/construction-set',
      exact: true,
      title: 'Construction Set',
      icon: <ReconciliationOutlined />,            
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` when you run your code in dev mode? Can you log the value?

Comment: i am trying to build in dev mode using this `npm run build
npm run run:dev` but getting an  error

Comment: and dev mode in the sense in local?

Comment: @DarioFiore could you please let me know the dev mode in the sense local or actual dev mode like as I pointed the above url

Answer (score 0):

When you run npm start, `NODE_ENV` is always equal to `development`, when you run npm test it is always equal to `test`, and when you run npm run build to make a production bundle, it is always equal to `production`.

In order to achieve your needed you could create a custom env variabile with suffix `REACT_APP_` and set value that you need (using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)).

Your script inside `package.json` should become something like that:

```
"build:dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=development <continue_script>"
```

Then const `isDevelopmentMode` will change with:

```
export const isDevelopmentMode = !process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT || process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === 'development';
```

Comment: ok, if i do like that so i can able to see the routes in local and dev environments? and we can consider dev as test environment here

Comment: I cannot change the isDevelopmentmode constant, what i am looking for is a variable that will hide the routes only in Prod mode and it will show the routes in all other environments

Comment: if i use like this `export const isProductionMode = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`  I believe it is equivalent to only prod mode right